# How to Save Html Formatted Text in Database Safely ? PHP - MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, security, content-management-system

I'm trying to develope a php cms. I just want to learn how to save an article with links safely in database. There are tutorials in internet but I couldn't find a tutorial for html formatted text. They always show for normal text.

> Example HTML Code

```
<p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
    tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
    consequat. <a href="http://www.gotosomewhere.com">Go to somewhere</a> Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
    cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
    proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</p>
```

Questions:

1. What is the best way to do that safely?
2. Should I change my text's format with a function while saving in database?
3. If I should how can I edit this article again?

I know this is a simple question according to most developers but I'm still learning and I want to make sure that everything is safe :)

Comment: It's better you use Markdown or other safe languages and store how Stack Overflow does. You can also render Markdown in HTML / PDF / DOC, or any format you would like.

Comment: If you use prepared/parameterized queries you can store it directly without worrying any special or malicious content in the text will mess with your db. I assume you are really thinking about how to _output_ this data in a secure manner. As everything else there are a lot of ways to solve that issue, like using html purifier, using/storing markdown instead of html, etc

Comment: Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would simply save the information with the tags between quotes and use the following :
http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php

Hope it helps, the second comment from the above site is a good example, more specifically

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php#86964